# Delete button doesn't work after adding element to array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, innerhtml, display

I have a problem when I want to add a new element (series) to the array and then display it on the list, the "Delete" button stops working. Apparently, if I add this new element to the array and don't display it on the list, the "Delete" button still works. However, when I display it on the list, the "Delete" button stops working.

```
'use strict';

let btnAddSeries = document.querySelector(".btn-primary");

let seriesForm = document.querySelector("#seriesForm");


// ARRAY OF SERIES

let listSeries = 
[
    {film: ['Breaking Bad', 'Better Call Saul', 'Game of Thrones', 'Ozark', 'Peaky Blinders', 'Stranger Things', 
            'Sex Eductaion', '13 Reasons Why', 'Skins', 'One of Us Is Lying'], genre: "Drama"},

    {film: ['Servant', 'Penny Dreadful', 'Them', 'The Haunting of Bly Manor', 'Sweet Home', 'The Haunting of Hill House',
             'Haunted', 'True Blood', 'The Midnight Club'], genre: "Horror"},

    {film: ['Rick and Morty', 'The Office US', 'The Office UK', 'Friends', 'Seinfeld', 'The Simpsons', 'The Good Place',
             'Two and a Half Men'], genre: "Comedy"}
]


class Series
{
    constructor(series, type)
    {
        this.series = series;
        this.type = type;
    }
}


class Display
{
    tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');

    add(libraryOfSeries) 
    {
        let uiString = `<tr class="series">
                            <td class="series-name">${libraryOfSeries.series}</td>
                            <td class="table-dark">${libraryOfSeries.type}</td>
                            <button class="btn1 btn-primary">Delete</button>
                        </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;
    }
}


// DISPLAY SERIES TO THE LIST

function displayGenre(series, genreToFilter)
{
    let filterSeries = series.find(item => item.genre === genreToFilter);

    for(let i of filterSeries.film)
    {
        let currentSeries = new Series(i, filterSeries.genre);

        let display = new Display;

        display.add(currentSeries)
    }
}


// CALLING THE DISPLAY FUNCTION

function updateUI()
{
    displayGenre(listSeries, "Drama");
    displayGenre(listSeries, "Comedy");
    displayGenre(listSeries, "Horror");
}
updateUI();



// ADDING A SERIES TO THE ARRAY AND UPDATE THE UI

seriesForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    let series = document.querySelector("#seriesName").value;
    let horror = document.querySelector("#horror");
    let comedy = document.querySelector("#comedy");
    let drama = document.querySelector("#drama");
    let type;


    if(horror.checked)
    {
        type = horror.value;
    }
    else if(comedy.checked)
    {
        type = comedy.value;
    }
    else if(drama.checked)
    {
        type = drama.value;
    }

    let thisSeries = listSeries.find(e => e.genre == type);

    thisSeries.film.unshift(series);


    // updating UI
    tableBody.innerHTML = "";
    updateUI();

    
    if(series == "")
    {
        alert("Fill up the form");
    }
})



// DELETE A SERIES FROM THE LIST

let btnDelete = document.querySelectorAll(".btn1");

for(let i of btnDelete)
{
    i.addEventListener("click", function(e)
    {
        let item = e.target;

        item.previousSibling.remove();

        item.remove();
    })
}
```

codeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/GasparBonari/lll/draft/happy-sun?file=%2Findex.html

Comment: You're only adding the listeners to the first set of buttons you add, not any subsequent ones. If you attach _one_ listener to the table instead ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)) you'll be able to catch _all_ events from all its children whether they were added dynamically or not.

Comment: Thank you man, that was definitely my issue. Thanks for your help and contribution!